# Is $g(\nabla_{e_0}X,)$ is equal to $\nabla_{e_0}g(X,)$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric , $e_0$ and $X$ vector field with $g(e_0,e_0)=-1$ .From the compatibility condition of the metric we have for another  field $Y$  we have
$$\nabla_{e_0}g(X,Y)= g(\nabla_{e_0}X,Y)+g(X,\nabla_{e_0}Y)$$
Now if put $e_0=e^{\mu}_0 \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ and since  $g(x,)=X^ag_{ab}dx^b$

\begin{multline} 
\nabla_{e_0}g(X,)= \nabla_{e_0}\left(X^ag_{ab}dx^b\right)=e^{\mu}_0\nabla_\mu\left(X^ag_{ab}dx^b\right)=e^{\mu}_0 \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\left(X^ag_{ab}\right)dx^b+X^ag_{ab}\nabla_\mu dx^b\ \right] = e^{\mu}_0 \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\left(X^ag_{ab}\right)-X^ag_{ac} \Gamma^c_{\mu b } \ \right]dx^b 
\end{multline}

Now $$\nabla_{e_0} X=e^{\mu}_0 \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}X^c+X^a \Gamma^c_{\mu a } \ \right]\frac{\partial}{\partial x^c}$$

so
$$g(\nabla_{e_0}X,)= e^{\mu}_0 \left[g_{c b} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}X^c+g_{c b}X^a \Gamma^c_{\mu a } \ \right]dx^b$$
Now in the book [*The Many Faces of Maxwell, Dirac and Einstein Equations*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-27637-3)

they claim that

$$\nabla_{e_0}g(X,)= g(\nabla_{e_0}X,)$$

Why is the last expression true?

Comment: This follows almost trivially from the first expression. The covariant derivative can't act on nothing.

Comment: @Eletie $\nabla_{e_0} $ is a one form

Comment: In local coords $\nabla_{e} = e^{\mu} \nabla_{\mu}$

Comment: @Eletie how can this solve my problem

Comment: It shows that the $g(X,\nabla_{e_{0}})$ term is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows immediately from metricity. In local coordinates,
$$
\nabla_e (g_{ab} X^{a})= e^c \nabla_{c}(g_{ab} X^{a})  = g_{ab} e^c \nabla_c X^a = g_{ab} \nabla_e X^a\ .
$$
In coordinate free notation you can see that $\nabla_{e}$ acting on nothing is still zero, so the $g(X,\nabla_{e})$ term vanishes.

---

Response to edit: this doesn't change the answer posted above - metricity, $\nabla_{a} g_{bc} =0$, immediately implies what I've written above.

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: @amiltonmoreira Sure, but do you understand what $\nabla_{e_0}$ represents?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: @amiltonmoreira I see the edit, but it makes no difference to the answer. It still follows quite straightforwardly from metric compatibility.

Comment: @amiltonmoreira also note your edit essentially answers the question too: that is $g(\nabla_{e_0} X,)$ in local coords.

Comment: I am not seeing how but I do some algebra to see if I arrive at the same expression

Comment: @amiltonmoreira In local coordinates $g(\nabla_e X,)$ is just $g_{ab} e^c \nabla_{c} X^a$. Expand the covariant derivative of the vector and you get exactly the expression you've written on your final line. But you don't need to go through this trouble, you can do it in just one step (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility condition give us
$$\left(\nabla_\mu g \right)_{ab}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}g_{ab}-\Gamma^c_{a\mu}g_{bc}-\Gamma^c_{b\mu}g_{ac}=0$$ and so
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}g_{ab}=\Gamma^c_{a\mu}g_{bc}+\Gamma^c_{b\mu}g_{ac} \tag1$$
Now
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\left(X^ag_{ab}\right)-X^ag_{ac} \Gamma^c_{\mu b }= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}X^ag_{ab} + X^a\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}g_{ab}-X^ag_{ac} \Gamma^c_{\mu b }$$

using $(1)$ we arrive at
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\left(X^ag_{ab}\right)-X^ag_{ac} \Gamma^c_{\mu b }= g_{c b} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}X^c+g_{c b}X^a \Gamma^c_{\mu a }$$
So the equality in the brackets give us the equality of the expression

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a coordinate free way, you can do the following. The covariant derivative commutes with contractions. The one form $g(X,\cdot)$ is the contraction of $g\otimes X$. Hence $\nabla_Yg(X,\cdot)$ is the contraction of $\nabla_Y(g\otimes X)$. By Leibnitz and metric compatibility the last expression is equal to $\nabla_Yg\otimes X+g\otimes\nabla_YX=g\otimes\nabla_YX$. Which contracts to $g(\nabla_YX,\cdot)$